# Transferring data from a calculator to a span

Tags: javascript, html, css

Hi I have a javascript code for a calcutor and I'm trying to transfer the result of the calculator with a button "Save" to a html  called Hours worked this week:. I'm a little bit lost and don't really know where to go from what I have. Can anyone help?

This is the code I have now:

```js
let display = document.getElementById('display');

let buttons = Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName('button'));

buttons.map( button => {
    button.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
        switch(e.target.innerText){
            case 'C':
                display.innerText = '';
                break;
            case '=':
                try{
                    display.innerText = eval(display.innerText);
                } catch {
                    display.innerText = "Error"
                }
                break;
            case 'Save':
                
            case '←':
                if (display.innerText){
                   display.innerText = display.innerText.slice(0, -1);
                }
                break;
            default:
                display.innerText += e.target.innerText;
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<div class="task">
        <form>
        <label for="TN">Task name: </label>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Task name" onkeyup="lettersOnly(this)">
        <br>
        <br>
        <label for="TN">Task date: </label>
        <input type="text" placeholder="MM/DD/YYYY" onkeyup="numbersOnly(this)" maxlength="10">
        <br>
        <br>
        <span id="hours">Hours worked this week:</span>
        <br>
        <br>
        <input type="button" id="button1" value="Submit Form"> 
        </form>
        </div>
        <section>
            <div class="calc">
                <div id="display"></div>
                <div class="buttons">
                    <div class="button">C</div>
                    <div class="button">/</div>
                    <div class="button">*</div>
                    <div class="button">&larr;</div>
                    <div class="button">7</div>
                    <div class="button">8</div>
                    <div class="button">9</div>
                    <div class="button">-</div>
                    <div class="button">4</div>
                    <div class="button">5</div>
                    <div class="button">6</div>
                    <div class="button">+</div>
                    <div class="button">1</div>
                    <div class="button">2</div>
                    <div class="button">3</div>
                    <div class="button">.</div>
                    <div class="button">0</div>
                    <div class="button">Save</div>
                    <div id="equal" class="button">=</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
```

Comment: `someElement.innerText = someValue` does exactly what it sounds like you're trying to describe... "transfer a value" to the HTML.  (Display a value on the page.)  What specifically isn't working here?  Can you provide a runnable [mcve] which demonstrates the problem, and indicate what debugging you have done?

Comment: @David They're trying to make the Save button put the result after "Hours worked this week:"

Comment: @SuperStormer yes exactly!

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
document.getElementById("hours").innerText = "Hours worked this week: " + eval(display.innerText)
```

Full code here:
[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pbstLh8f/)

Comment: FWIW, `eval` should not be used in actual code.